# How to make the right margin twice the size of the left margin

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed-size inner div within a variable-width outer div.

```css
#outer { width: 100%; }
#inner { width: 80px; }
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

I want the inner div to be placed inside outer div as follows:

```
[Npx of empty space][80px fixed-size inner div][2Npx of empty space]
```

where N is some number. As the window size changes, N will change, but the right will remain twice the size of the left. Is it possible to do with CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative to Mr Lister's positioning option we can use `calc` on the margins.

```css
#outer {
  width: 100%;
}
#inner {
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-left: calc((100% - 80px) / 3);
  margin-right: calc((100% - 80px) / (3 * 2));
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. I don't do a lot of front end work. Is calc well supported enough? I've always been curious about whether it should be used. I know IE11 sometimes does weird things with nested calculations as per "calc((100% - 80px) / 3);"

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a fall-back for when calc is not supported? Will it degrade gracefully?

Comment: If you really want to make it bullet-proof you can just do the calculations beforehand but I thought I would show the workings...

Comment: @George For a fallback, you can use d3v_1's solution. Just make sure to write the styles without `calc` first and then the ones with `calc`.

Comment: @Paulie_D I actually tried writing things like `((100% - 80px) / 6)` in my solution, but for whatever reason I couldn't make it work. Not sure what you're doing differently.

Comment: This may be a good solution for a fixed sized (e.g. 80px) element. Is there some `height` function that can be used with `calc` for non-fixed sized elements?

Answer (score 3):

First we set both margins of the inner div to `auto`, so each margin would measure (100% - 80px) / 2. Then we need to shift the div 1/3 of that to the left, so we position it relatively, by (100% - 80px) / 6.

```css
#outer {
  width: 100%;
}
#inner {
  width: 80px;
  
  margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
  position: relative; left: calc(13.33px - 16.67%);
  
  /* to make it visible */
  background: cyan; height: 30px
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

(Note that the last line of the CSS is for visibility purposes in this snippet only.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it something like this, it should work out well as you resize it. Feel free to tweak the percentages slightly.

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner-container">
        <div id="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#outer {
    width: 100%;
}
#inner-container {
  width: 66%;
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;
}
#inner {
  width: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I've made a codepen for you here if you want to play around with it. I've included some background colours to help illustrate what's happening.

[Example CSS offsetting](http://codepen.io/devronbaldwin/pen/qaBRap)

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice option. Looks like it will not be exact unless #inner div's width is negligible compared to outer div's width. But I like that it does not use calc, so would be the proffered solution in some cases.

Comment: When mixing percentages and pixels you'll never get it exactly right without calc() or some jQuery doing the same thing as calc()

Answer (score 1):

If the width of box is known then you can avoid `calc` as follows. You need to embed the width (80px) and left margin (= 80px/3) in your CSS.

```css
#outer {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
#inner {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: palevioletred;
  position: relative;
  /*
   * push 33.3% of parent width towards right
   * pull 33.3% of own width towards left
   */
  left: 33.3%;
  margin-left: -26.6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```